# how to upload multiple images to server ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-uploading

I am trying to upload Image From my IOS device to server. when upload single image file to server it is successfully uploaded to my server. i want to upload multiple image files to server how can i do this.

```
// COnvert Image to NSData
NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"], 1.0f);

// set your URL Where to Upload Image
NSString *urlString = @"http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/imgupload.php";

// set your Image Name
NSString *filename = @"icon";

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.
NSMutableURLRequest* request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.png\"\r\n",filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    [postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:dataImage]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:postbody];

// Get Response of Your Request
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response  %@",responseString);
```

Muliple images upload attempted code

```
  -(void)uploadImageToServer:(NSArray*)arrUploadData withTreatmentDetails:(NSDictionary *)dictArguments url:(NSString*)url
  {
// COnvert Image to NSData


// set your URL Where to Upload Image
NSString *urlString = @"http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/imgupload.php";

// set your Image Name


// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.
NSMutableURLRequest* request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
for (int i=0; i<[arrUploadData count]; i++)
{
    NSData *dataImage = [[arrUploadData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"photographyData"];
    NSString *filename = [[arrUploadData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"photographyimagename"];
    if (dataImage)
    {
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.png\"\r\n",filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    [postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:dataImage]];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
}
[request setHTTPBody:postbody];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response  %@",responseString);

}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to add the additional image(s) to `postBody`?

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated attempted code please check it now..

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, You can do it by using NSMutableArray**

*For Example :*

```
 NSMutableArray  *arrayImageData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

**Take images from imagepicker**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  NSString *filePath,*path;

 NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],1);
     [arrayImageData addObject:dataImage];

    filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"screenShot1.png"];


    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**At the time of posting image on Server use following code**

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayImageData count]; i++)
        {

            [request setPostValue:[[MYUtility getInstance] base64StringFromNSData:[arrayImageData objectAtIndex:i]] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%d", i + 1]];
        }
```

Hope this will help for you...I used this code for saving multiple images on server.